# Organize SSRS Subscriptions in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Our organization is running SQL Server 2012 Standard and I have dozens (near 100) of SSRS report subscriptions hanging out there.  Unfortunately, they are all piled into one long list.  Is there any way to organize the report subscriptions in folders?  I am thinking that's a definite "no" as I have never found a way to do this.  Right now I have individual subscriptions for dozens of individuals as well as a few other subscriptions that get sent out to just a mailing list.

If this isn't available in SQL Server 2012 Standard (and again, I am guessing it isn't), does anyone know if newer versions of SQL Server (and maybe a different edition of SQL Server) can do this?

Many thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, with the Standard version.. there is only so much you can do.. if you have access to the Enterprise version, then  you can get data driven subscriptions that make a world of difference.

Comment: Thanks, Harry.  I believe that answered my question and confirmed my suspicions.  I appreciate it!  Not sure how to mark your comment as an answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, with the Standard version.. there is only so much you can do.. if you have access to the Enterprise version, then you can get data driven subscriptions that make a world of difference. – Harry 2 days ago

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to be able to get a better view of all of the subscriptions you have set up then you could create a report that queries the ReportServer database.  This would allow you to see which subscriptions belong to which reports and how the report is being distributed.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  This is better than nothing.  :)